# How to pass data to a RESTful web service?

Tags: php, json, rest

I am working on an API. Where I have to work on restful web services. I am very new to it. What I have learned from the API documentation is that I have to pass data to a specific URL. I have all necessary data and that URL. 
But I did not find any way to pass data by POST method to a restful web service  (at that URL).

I have learned this from the API documentation:

- **URI:** "https://host:port/v1/merchant/transaction/create"
- **HTTP Method:** POST
- **Header parameters**

  - **Content-Type:** application / json
  - **UserId:** XXXXX
  - **Token:** XXXXXXXXXXX

And it's a RESTful setup that transmits data using JSON format via HTTPS.

Can anyone please help me how to pass data via POST method to that URL?

Comment: From your tags I assume that you want to implement the API call in PHP?

Comment: yes bro, u are right. But I can't find a way, what's the standard way to write such code!  I have all information already mentioned.

Comment: As I mentioned below, you can either use a combination of `json_encode()` and the cURL extension, which allows you to send any kind of HTTP request to a target address. Alternatively, you can pick a library to use, for example [HTTPful](http://phphttpclient.com/) or [Guzzle](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). If you're not very familiar with PHP yet, a library might be the better solution for you.

Comment: Thanks bro. But I am sorry,I know about json_encode(). But I don't know, how can i pass and call web serices by using those data, url. Can u please tell me any tutorials links, where can I get proper idea with example code ........

Answer (score -1):

Just replace

```
Content-Type: application / json
```

With

```
Content-Type: application / x-www-form-urlencoded
```

If the API you are using has an option.

Otherwise, you can still access data as $_POST method but in the form of json, then you will have to use json_decode($_POST) to convert it back to array.

Comment: If the API requires you to use `application/json` as Content-Type, you really don't have the option to "just replace" it with anything else. This is not helpful to the OP and probably just adds to the confusion.

Comment: @Till Helge, You are right, but as it's not mentioned which REST API,Framework or Tool is being used so I wrote the solution to change Content-Type as it can be change at code or Tool level if permit.

Comment: You're missing the point. He's not implementing the REST interface, he wants to use it. There is some REST API he needs to send data to. So what he should use is `json_encode()` to package the data he needs to send and then employ for example the Curl-Extension to send the request. Or just some library that makes it even easier. I just don't have the time to explain that in great detail right now. Want to do the honors? ;)

Comment: thanks all of u. But problem is not in Content-Type. I want to pass data to that url, but I don't find how to pass data to that url. Which will return JOSN data.